# How to solve or choose the smoothing parameter phi in solving for the Nonlinear trend exponential smoothing?

Tags: forecasting, exponential-smoothing

In forecasting, to solving for the nonlinear trend exponential smoothing can you just choose any value of ϕ or is there a way to solve for it?

Comment: What's $\phi$ in this case?

Comment: it's the trend-modification parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can see how several different $\phi$ values compare at predicting. For example, you can compare one-step-ahead prediction errors (especially if predicting the next value is mostly what you need your predictions for).

This would be done by leaving out much of the later part of your data and predicting the next observation, finding the prediction error ($y_t-\hat{y}_t$), adding that $y$ back into the data, predicting the next one and so on. Then you can look at sums of squares (of those errors) or sums of absolute values or weighted sums of squares (to more heavily weight the recent data, say) as a criterion. Do that over each of a bunch of $\phi$ values to find one that does well at prediction.

There are a variety of ways of evaluating models discussed [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5) (Hyndman and Athana­sopou­los, *Forecasting Principles and Practice*)

Comment: How about in using this equation [link](https://imgur.com/a/jf8lR) ?

S is the smoothed level at the end of t,
T is the smoothed trend at the end of t

Comment: We're using the book Quantitative Approaches for Management by Levin and I'm a bit confused on how to find the value for it. It was just stated in examples that the computer picked a value for it. But I wanna know how to do it manually.

Comment: What's described in my answer should work for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "does well at prediction"?

Comment: See my answer "*...you can look at sums of squares (of those errors) or sums of absolute values or weighted sums of squares (to more heavily weight the recent data, say) as a criterion*"... it's up to *you* to decide what you want to do well at - pick one, or substitute another. Whichever criterion you use (or using one of the other methods at the link I gave) this will be pretty tedious by hand but easily automated on a computer.